# DateTime Editor Template only for Create View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Editor Template for my Date fields which sets the current date if the field is null.

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

@{
    var date = Model as DateTime?; // local reference to a DateTime? 

    if (!date.HasValue                     // check if it is not null 
        || date.Equals(default(DateTime))) // check if it is not default 01/01/0001
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", date.Value.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "date" })
 }
```

I would like to apply this template to only my Create Views.

When I edit a record the above code populates the current date for fields that I had intentionally left as null as the date was unknown.

Wondering if my code can be amended to accommodate this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this.

First way is to pass in a flag through your ViewData, something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeDate, new { nowIfNull = true })
```

Then update your template:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>

@{
    var date = Model as DateTime?; // local reference to a DateTime? 

    if ((!date.HasValue                     // check if it is not null 
        || date.Equals(default(DateTime))) // check if it is not default 01/01/0001
        && ((bool?)ViewData["nowIfNull"] ?? false)) // check if it should set to now if null
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    @Html.TextBox("", date == null ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0:d}", date.Value.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "date" })
 }
```

Another way is to default this to `DateTime.Now` in your controller -- or even better, a mapper -- when you create a new model. This separates the concerns of setting the default where it belongs, in your controller/mapper instead of the view.

Comment: Getting Nullable object must have a value when I use the above!

Comment: I was missing a paren (updated w/ the fix), not sure if that was the issue, but I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: No errors now. I needed to amend all of my date fields. It's not working as I had hoped though. I wanted the date fields in the edit views to be left null if they were null when the record was created. At the minute they have the current date if they were left null.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirement then. When you create a new record, do you want to default to Now or null? And when you edit a record w/ a null date, should it leave it as null, or change it to Now?

Comment: When I create a new record it should default to Now. When I edit a record with a null date it should leave it as null.

Comment: Then for your new record form, use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeDate, new { nowIfNull = true })`. For your edit record form, use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeDate)`

Comment: That gives an error Nullable object must have a value on my edit views.

Comment: That's because of the `date.Value.ToShortDateString()` in your template. I have updated the code above to fix that issue.